# aws congnito user pool migration to the new account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have total 600 users in the aws congnito user pool in my old aws account , and i want to move/migrate all the users to my new aws account. It is possible to migrate aws congnito users from one aws account to another.

Please Help Me.

I checked through every document linked to Congnito, but I was unable to find a document for moving Congnito users between AWS accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to use [cognito-backup-restore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cognito-backup-restore) npm tool. It's easy to use and oriented to What you require, but there are some important points to take into account:

- You need the AWS CLI and security credentials installed and well configured locally, preferably use IAM roles to access Cognito.
- You're backing up users from Cognito user pool to a JSON file locally, so do it in a safe environment and remove the file after restoring the backup.
- There is no way of getting passwords of the users in Cognito, so you may need to ask them to make use of ForgotPassword to recover their account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user migration Lambda trigger as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html