# Migrate AWS Cognito User Pool to another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there a mechanism to export a Cognito User Pool to another account?

I see I can import users from a CSV, but I can't see an export feature. I guess I can List users with an API call and put them into a CSV.

But how to retrieve passwords?

Comment: You won't be able to get passwords, but try the following proposal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74809345/7075674

Answer (score 0):

Finally I will try this solution using a Lambda trigger as described here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html